# The reason of Bartholomeo Kuma's devil fruit named as Nikyu-Nikyu no Mi?

Tags: one-piece

Nikyu-Nikyu no Mi is devil fruit that eaten by Bartholomeo Kuma, this fruit can be translated as Paw-Paw Fruit.

The power of this fruit are it can repelling any attack, or pain from our body as we can see in Thriller Bark arc when Kuma repelling the pain from Luffy.
This fruit also can make other peoples flying for few days to somewhere place in the world.

What I'm ask here is what the reason behind a paw that can "repel"? Is there any myth or something that make this fruit named as Nikyu-Nikyu no Mi/Paw-Paw Fruit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paw-Paw fruit grants the user the ability to repel everything they touch, and is physically represented as paws on the user's palms, making the user a Paw Human. 
The Paw has variety of uses that leaves a paw-pad imprint resembling the pads on his palms.

- [Cats uses one paw to repel inferior life forms](http://bbs.boingboing.net/t/cats-using-one-paw-to-repel-inferior-life-forms/56922/3). **The Paw Of Do-Not-Want**. Which might also be the reason behind a paw that can "repel" of your question.
   Video: https://twitter.com/boingboing/status/596558460382220288
- The fruit's name, **Nikyu**, comes from the word "Nikukyū" (肉球?) which means "Paw" in Japanese.  Ref: [Nikyu Nikyu no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Nikyu_Nikyu_no_Mi)
- I did a little search online if there is a significant reason why its called Nikyu-Nikyu no Mi/Paw-Paw Fruit but I found none that its related to myths or something. So the name "Paw-Paw" is basically just from its Japanese name counter part "Nikyu-Nikyu".

Comment: ooh, **The Paw Of Do-Not-Want** I think I can agree with that XD I guess it's more like a pun rather than a myth then...

Answer (score -1):

This will sound a bit nutty, but I would add to bot's "Niku-kyuu" answer that it may be a Disney reference? Baloo the Bear from the Jungle Book sings "When you pick a pawpaw (fruit), or a prickly pear, and you prick a raw paw, well next time beware!" Kuma's catchphrase of asking where you would go on a trip (and sending people to their personal hell/paradise) I think is likewise a reference to Brer Bear as depicted in Song of the South, who got very excited about Brer Rabbit's "Laughin' Place" that promises both honey and bees. It even lines up nicely with how the final treasure island is called Laugh Tale -- everybody's looking for the pot of (liquid) gold...

I'm personally persuaded of the Song of the South reference due to Oda linking racialized exclusion from theme parks with a history of slavery on Saobody, and foreshadowing this set up with the shadow zombies (ie slaves) in use at "Thriller Bark", itself a mutation of the phrase Amusement Park (with a Michael Jackson reference thrown in for good measure). I'd even argue that the Davy Back fight was foreshadowing, the way it had sailors FORCED INTO SERVITUDE in the midst of a BIG HAPPY CARNIVAL. They even sold Foxy merchandise like he was Mickey Mouse.

And if the other Disney references pan out, I'd guess Aokiji is partly a reference to the "blue bird" from Zip-a-dee-doo-dah, since they're cracking jokes about discrimination like 2 or 3 pages into his introduction. Maybe Water 7 is Splash Mountain! I could go on, but that's the gist of it